# Akka , priority order events

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have heard a lot of good things about Akka.
I have a stream of price , and I need to create two moving average of the price.
And finally I have a strategy that listens to these signals => price, moving average price 1 and moving average price 2 and makes some decisions.

I implemented this via actors but unfortunately I have a problem of order, that a) I don’t know how to specify a timestamp or priority order to the messages or events generated.

```
final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("backtest");    
final ActorRef strat = ActorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Strategy.class));
final ActorRef acref = ActorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(PriceCSVReader.class));
final ActorRef ma5 = ActorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(MovingAverage.class,5,"price"));
final ActorRef ma20 = ActorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(MovingAverage.class,20,"price"));

actrSystem.eventStream().subscribe(strat,PriceEvent.class);    
actrSystem.eventStream().subscribe(ma5,PriceEvent.class);    
actrSystem.eventStream().subscribe(ma20,PriceEvent.class);

acref.tell(new ReadPriceFromCSV("c:\price.csv"));
```

Where PriceEvent is a simple class with a string id and a double value.
Moving average class listens to the price and compute a moving average and create a new PriceEvent each time.

The strategy listens to all these PriceEvents and using their id can distinguish them.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: It is a lot of code, I try to add some part of it.